# xcode iOS business application

Tags: ios

I am a complete novice when it comes to iOS app development. I have designed and submitted my business app to the app store and it is going alone ok. Only thing is I have to change, add or subtract products as our business changes. Is there a way where I don't have to write new code and resubmit to the apple store. e.g. some server based drag & drop portal I could use instead of having to change through Xcode and resubmitting. it is a fairly basic tabbed based application with maps

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your products are stored in a database, you could build up a REST Webservice to access them from your app.
If you do not have the programming skills to do so, a possible solution could be to use a UIWebView in your app that loads HTML-pages with your products, so you just need some basic html skills to update the products.
Note that if there are any links to other websites your app probably has to be ratet 17+.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :)